# Serve static ressources in vaadin

Tags: java, spring-boot, jetty, servlet-3.0, vaadin-flow

I want some static resources to be served via HTTP by a vaadin14/spring-boot server.

As I understand from this [blog post](https://vaadin.com/blog/vaadin-10-and-static-resources), there is a convention that all resources placed in `META-INF/resources`(and some other places) will be served as static content (web fragments)

As an example, i place the following file in:

`src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/asd.txt`

and maven puts it into JAR as expected:

`META-INF/resources/asd.txt`

When I ask for `localhost:8080/asd.txt` the results differ, depending on how the app was started:

- IDE/eclipse: works (Start the Application.main() method)
- packaged jar: the vaadin router picks up the request and thells me that there is no route available.

How do i tell vaadin/jetty (or whom ever?) to also serve this static repo when packaged?

We are using vaadin 14.7.0 with spring-boot-starter-parent 2.4.5

Comment: I have the exact same issue... @markus did you ever found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue but upgrading to Vaadin 23 and Spring boot 2.5.3 solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

It works also in a packaged jar, exactly as you describe. You can test by doing e.g.

```
npx @vaadin/cli init hello-resources
cd hello-resources
echo "Hello" > src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/asd.txt
mvn
```

Now http://localhost:8080/asd.txt returns "Hello"

```
mvn clean package -Pproduction
java -jar target/hello-resources-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Now http://localhost:8080/asd.txt also returns "Hello"